# iOS Architecture and Xcode Organiser window

Tags: xcode

Can anyone tell me where I can get more information regarding iOS architecture and xcode organiser window. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're just getting started with iOS programming, I'd recommend either checking out the "[Getting Started](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started)" documentation that Apple provides on its website, or grabbing a book that provides an overview of Objective-C and Cocoa Touch from your local bookstore. I've always enjoyed the stuff that Hillegass & Co. at Big Nerd Ranch produce, so I might recommend starting with their "[iPhone Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242)" manual.

Xcode's Organizer window is a little strange at first, since there are no real counterparts to it in Eclipse or Visual Studio, but most of the step-by-step tutorials that you can find online and in iOS programming books typically do walk through your use of the Project Organizer for managing your devices and provisioning profiles. (This is all it's really useful for, unless you start getting into advanced use of a version control system.) If you're a casual or beginning iOS developer, then once you get your development devices set up and your development profiles loaded onto those devices (documented clearly in step-by-step fashion on the Apple Developer site), you probably won't come back to the Organizer much unless you need to grab an output log or a screenshot from your device.